# Where to generate JSON schemas that change depending on model fields?

Tags: json, django, postgresql, model-view-controller, django-templates

In Django, I need to represent payment details for a client. These payment details depend on which country the client is in. For example, US has a Routing Number and Account Number while Canada has Institution, Transit, Account Numbers and anything European has IBAN and BIC.

I think data like this is exactly what JSON storage is made for so I used PostgreSQL's JSONField.

```
class Client(models.Model):
    country = CountryField(blank=True)
    payment_details = JSONField()
```

After some time, I figured the best place to populate the JSONField with a schema appropriate for the country is in the frontend, because in the backend, I would have to wait for the model to be saved first, which is silly from the user's perspective.

Here's the problem: I have to fill the JSONField with something like this:

```
{
    "IFSC Number": "FDSAFDSA",
    "Whatever Number": "12410202"
}
```

Right now I have the backend checking to see if the country changed, and then changing the schema in the JSONField accordingly. But this means that whenever someone changes the country, they have to first save the model before they can add their payment details!

So this has to be done in the frontend, but I don't know how. I'd have to do this in Django's admin pages, and also the actual end-user facing frontend! The end-user facing frontend might just be some jQuery, but I'm unfamiliar with overriding Django admin templates.

Not only that, if I add a new blank schema for some other country:

```
{
    "Banking Number 1": "",
    "Banking Code whatever"
}
```

I'll have to modify two things now, which is a sign that this isn't the right way to do things.

Comment: i think django admin doesnot support the json field. Not sure about it

Comment: Your approach seems good; a simple google search should give you ways to get JSON editor in Django admin. 
I wanted to mention that it sounds like you are giving access to users to your Django admin. If that is the case, I would like to mention that you are not using the admin interface in an intended way. It is not to be exposed to the user. The recommended way is to create a regular form.

Comment: Yes, I am going to create a regular form, not letting end users access the admin interface. But editing the JSON in Django admin is not the problem - that's not what I'm asking. Anybody with access to the admin should be able to edit JSON anyway...